# ONAP honolulu getting Error when build A1 Policy Management Service container with oran code

Tags: java, maven

root@k8s-master-node-01:~/oran/a1-policy-management# mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.onap.ccsdk.oran:a1-policy-management-service:1.1.7-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.onap.ccsdk.parent:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 24, column 13
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.onap.ccsdk.oran:a1-policy-management-service:1.1.7-SNAPSHOT (/root/oran/a1-policy-management/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.onap.ccsdk.oran:a1-policy-management-service:1.1.7-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.onap.ccsdk.parent:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 24, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
root@k8s-master-node-01:~/oran/a1-policy-management#

Comment: Here is the pom.xml snippet for parent:


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.onap.ccsdk.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.